# How to accelerate `import numpy` by excluding unneeded submodules

Tags: python, performance, numpy, module, python-import

We have a test suite that executes hundreds of Python scripts. After optimizing our own code, we found that most of the test time is now spent on loading numpy and matplotlib. Let's focus here on numpy.

```
time python3 -c 'import numpy'
```

gives me 360 ms.

The command

```
python3 -X importtime -c 'import numpy'
```

shows that a substantial fraction of that time is spent on loading submodules `numpy.fft`, `numpy.polynomial`, `numpy.random`, which we do not need. Maybe we need not even `numpy.lib`. How to prevent these submodules from being loaded?

Our naive attempt

```
python3 -X importtime 'from numpy import core'
```

brings no improvement; modules other than `core` are still listed, and the load time is essentially unchanged.

Comment: If you examine the __init__ files in github you will find that the imports are indeed numerous.  Unless you can narrow down the parts you actually need, then you may be out of luck... see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/__init__.py as you used in your example

Comment: Interesting issue, maybe just steal the source-code that you need from numpy directly rather than trying to import it if performance matters that much?

Comment: have you considered running the scripts from a shared interpreter?